# Java Call constructor multiple times

Tags: java

I have a class that's essentially like:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  public void reinitialize() {
    super();  // illegal
  }
}
```

Basically, I want to call the constructor again to reinitialize. I can't refactor out the initialization code into its own method, because `Parent` is a library class I can't modify the source of.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you wanna reinitialize parent or child??

Comment: Create an `initialize()` method which does what your constructor currently does.  Then, your constructor and `reinitialize()` should both simply call `initialize()`.

Comment: @Gan: Child (so I could instead call `this()`). Vulcan: As mentioned, I cannot refactor due to not having the source for `Parent`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. Even at the JVM bytecode level, a chain of `<init>` methods (constructors) can be called at most once on any given object.

The usual answer is to refactor the code out into a normal instance method, but as you said, this is impossible.

The best you can do is to find a way to redesign to get around the need for reinitialization. Alternatively, if there's a specific behavior in the parent constructor you need, you might be able to duplicate it yourself.

Comment: You can follow the design principle "favor composition over inheritance" (Effective Java), thus making `Child` *having* a `Parent` (composition), instead of *being* one (inheritance). This way, you can exchange the parent with a new instance, thus calling the constructor.

Comment: That's included under the refactoring option. I'm assuming that the OP can't do this due to library design.

Comment: As I understood it, s/he can't change `Parent`, but `Child` is a subclass written by himself.

Comment: If the restriction is only on calling <init> more than once, can't it be worked around by instantiating `Child` using Objenesis (which will skip the first call to the constructor)?

Comment: @user833771 No - ctor can be called at most once at the bytecode level. In particular, it can only be called on an uninitialized object, and not at all on an already initialized object. Even if you use dark magic to create an initialized object without calling the ctor, you can't call the ctor on it because the verifier sees it as already initialized.

Comment: I'm trying to reconcile what you're saying with ability to call multiple, different constructors on the same object with `this(.)` c.f. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html. Could you help explain why your statement does not include this scenario?

Comment: @flow2k You can only call a constructor once within any given constructor. Each constructor's bytecode is verified independently. The fact that you're calling multiple methods on the same runtime object is irrelevant. I could explain in more detail, but not within the confines of a Stack Overflow  comment. Feel free to ask a question if you still don't understand.

Comment: @Antimony For some reason I initially read your Answer as "...a constructor can be called at most once on any given object"; but now reading it more closely, I think I should have read it as "a chain of constructors can be called at most once on any given object", which would then make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I can see how my initial answer is confusing. If you call a chain of constructors, each constructor will see the object as uninitialized on entry and initialized after the chained constructor returns. Ultimately, it is java/lang/Object's constructor that does the actual initialization.

Answer (score 3):

The only work around for this is to either

- create a new object each time you need to "re-intialise" it.
- use delegation instead of inheritance, even if you have to use both.  By using delegation you can replace the instance.
- create a re-initialise method which does much the same thing as the parent constructor. e.g. replace fields or clear collections, using reflections if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is provide a static method which returns a new Child object. Alternatively, you can simply create a new Child object in the client code. Either way, it sounds like you will be unable to reuse an existing object.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. One of them is create another method, for example "init". This "init" method should be invoked from either the constructor or the reinitialize method.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in the question, I can't modify the parent class' constructor.